# How to check if the log has a certain message when a method from the helper spec is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to `Rspec`.
I am trying to test whether I get a required message in the `test.log` file when i try to run a `helper` method in `helper_spec.rb`. 
I have searched a lot but only found how to check a message printing using `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it should be enough to check whether the logger has been called which can be accomplished with

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:level).with("your log message")
```

(substitute `:level` with the level you're calling the logger with).